# CSS how to target 2 attributes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

OK if I want to target an `<input>` tag with `type="submit"` I can do so like:

```
input[type=submit]
```

Also if I want to target an `<input>` tag with `value="Delete"` I can do so like:

```
input[value=Delete]
```

But How can I target an `<input>` tag with BOTH?

Comment: What about selecting whether an attribute is present with any value? Would something like `input[type=number][step]` select all number inputs with the step attribute?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
input[type=submit][value=Delete]
```

You're chaining selectors. Each step narrows your search results:

```
input
```

finds all inputs.

```
input[type=submit]
```

narrows it to submits, while

```
input[type=submit][value=Delete]
```

narrows it to what you need.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [multiple attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) as follows:

```
input[type=submit][value=Delete] {
    /* some rules */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just chain the attribute selectors

```
input[type="submit"][value="delete"]
```