# OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError at WebElement Submit click

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to automate a scenario for some web pages using C#, Selenium and Chrome Webdriver, where Submit button click on the page will submit the sendkeys values.
however when Submit is clicked, it's throwing an `UnpackAndThrowOnError` error in Visual Studio Test explorer Window (`Nunit`).

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-4" name="postType" value="Submit">Submit<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
```

[image]

Detailed Error Description:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(ResponseerrorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary'2 parameters)<br>
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
at Onrsr.Specflow.Sampletest.occurrence() in C:\Users\manish.sharma\source\repos\Onrsr.Specflow\Onrsr.Specflow\Sampletest.cs:line 180
```

I've tried the below code options, but they all are failing at submitBtnReview.Click()

```
IWebElement submitBtnReview = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'Submit')]"));
submitBtnReview.Click();

IWebElement submitBtnReview = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[value='Submit']"));
submitBtnReview.Click();

IWebElement submitBtnReview = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary mr-4']"));
submitBtnReview.Click();

IWebElement submitBtnReview = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='submit'][value='Submit']"));
submitBtnReview.Click();
```

I've also tried using `submitBtnReview.Submit()` with the `IwebElement` above, however it's crashing the page.

I'm using latest version of Selenium.WebDriver (3.141.0) and Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver (2.43.0), and using chrome version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) on windows 10 machine.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

---

**[05/12/2018]** - thank you for all valuable feedbacks -  I've now also tried the below and they are failing at `submitBtnReview.Click()` with a new error:

`Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: Element <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-4" name="postType" value="Submit">...</button> is not clickable at point (1792, 876). Other element would receive the click: <footer class="border-top bg-white">...</footer> (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)`

```
IWebElement submitBtnReview = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[type='submit'][value='Submit'][name='postType']"));
IWebElement submitBtnReview = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(@class, 'btn') and contains(@class, 'btn-primary') and contains(@class, 'mr-4')]"));
IWebElement submitBtnReview = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary mr-4']"));
IWebElement submitBtnReview =  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary mr-4' and @name='postType'][normalize-space()='Submit']")));
IWebElement submitBtnReview = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(element_is_present(By.CssSelector("button[type='submit'][value='Submit'][name='postType']")))


public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> element_is_present(By by)
    { return driver =>
        { IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(by);
            try
            { if (element != null && element.Displayed && element.Enabled)
                { return element;
                }
                else
                { return null;
                }
            }catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            { return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

Setting some breakpoints, showing `submitBtnReview` LocationOnScreen coordinates with a new error, and this might be related.

```
    LocationOnScreen = '((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteCoordinates)((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement)submitBtnReview ).Coordinates).LocationOnScreen' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'
```

Submit button details from debugging:

[image]

Error image:
[image]

Hope this additional information helps in finding the cause.

Comment: "...crashing the page ..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: @JohnB ,thanks of your comment. I've updated the description to reflect the issue correctly. I'm getting the error in Visual Studio Test explorer Window (Nunit). On successful web page submit click I was expecting to move to see a submission no on the web page .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exact answer so far, just some observations. 3 of given locators look incorrect, although 1 looks ok.

1) By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'Submit')]")); ---> Looks correct --- [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath)

Suggestion: if text value is modified by any of given element `class` values and a button is **shown on a screen** as 'SUBMIT' (all caps) or submit (all lowercase) you should use it in xpath as well to be "//button[contains(.,'SUBMIT')]" or "//button[contains(.,'submit')]" .

2) By.CssSelector("input[value='Submit']")); ---> *By.CssSelector("**button**[value='Submit']"));* --- your tag is `<button>` not `<input>`

3) By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary mr-4']"); ---> *By.XPath("//button[**contains(@class, 'btn') and contains(@class, 'btn-primary') and contains(@class, 'mr-4')**])* --- [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881044/how-to-get-html-elements-with-multiple-css-classes)

4) By.CssSelector("input[type='submit'][value='Submit']")); ---> By.CssSelector("**button**[type='submit'][value='Submit']")); --- your tag is `<button>` not `<input>` [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397180/css-how-to-target-2-attributes)

Before clicking, make sure the element is clickable

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementIsClickable(By locator)
{
    return driver =>
    {
        var element = driver.FindElement(locator);
        return (element != null && element.Displayed && element.Enabled) ? element : null;
    };
}
```

Usable in something like:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var clickableElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("id"))
```

[original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057031/webdriver-how-to-wait-until-the-element-is-clickable-in-webdriver-c-sharp)

***[Addition after question as edited]***
The error states that you have an element and that selenium is not able to click on it at the point. [the problem is described and solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)

In my opinion, the most stable yet the hackiest way is to try out with the **javascript click** (it just **have to** click if you have an element on the screen, and based on the examples you **do have** it):

```
IJavaScriptExecutor ex = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
ex.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
```

***Another case*** is to make sure your element is located in the **visible area** of a browser (you can see/click it during debug without any manual scrolling). If it's not visible or not entirely visible - **scroll to it before clicking**.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", Webelement);
```

***Double check suggestion:***  make sure that there is exactly the one element with such locator. The usual case is when you think that you found 'the right' element but selenium founds the first-match and it is not the one you want.

***Another suggestion*** is that your element might change *it's position after you found it*. So you found it, saved to a variable and then for some reason the page layout changed (e.g. something async load finished). You can carefully pay attention to how your page loads. Does layout change? If yes - you can create a custom wait function that will check that element coordinates does not change for, let's say, 1-2 seconds.

Comment: I've tried all the above options as you explained @Vladmir, however still getting the same error at submitBtnReview.Click();

Comment: Unfortunately, error log is either not full, or just don't have enough details, but maybe the element is not clickable at the moment. Updated my answer

Comment: I've updated the issue with some additional finding and I hope you can help me again here.

Comment: @ManishSharma updated my answer with some suggestions

Comment: I can't thank you enough - you are a lifesaver. Submit button was not located in the visible area of a browser,and adding Javascript to scroll solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The element looks to be a dynamic element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.mr-4[name='postType'][value='Submit']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary mr-4' and @name='postType'][normalize-space()='Submit']"))).Click();
  ```
- **Note**: As you are using *ChromeDriver v2.43* ensure that you are using *Chrome v69-71*

Comment: I've updated the issue with some additional findings and I hope you can help me here again.